# Evaluating $\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ and $\sec^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{2}\right)$. Why are my answers ($5\pi/6$ and $3\pi/4$) incorrect?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

$$\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

$$\sec^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{2}\right)$$

I know that they are set up like $\sec(y)=x$ ...

$$\sec(y)=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\sec(y)=-\sqrt{2}$$

I got $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ for the first one and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ for the second, but these are wrong and I'm not sure why.

The only feedback I got was "An inverse trigonometric function takes a numeric value as input, and returns an angle as the output."

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: I agree that your answers are correct. Perhaps the source of the feedback has a bias for degrees in representing angles.

Comment: Please show us your definition of ${\rm sec}^{-1}$.

Comment: Alternatively, @Blue, perhaps the arbiter of answers wanted the word “radians” after the numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answer is looking for degrees in which case, you have 150$^\circ$ for the first one and 135$^\circ$ for the second one.

Comment: That's right, thanks Blue, just made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The restricted domain for $\sec$ is not consistently defined.  Some texts use;

$$y=\sec^{-1} x \iff \sec y = x \mbox{ and } y\in [0,\pi/2)\cup [\pi, 3\pi/2). $$

So perhaps that is your snag.  The reason for choosing this domain is that it makes the derivative formula nicer.

Comment: Yikes!  A derivative formula for a discontinuous function!

Comment: @OscarLanzi  It's not discontinuous everywhere.  If you use the OP's domain, the derivative has an absolute value in it.  If you use mine, you don't.

Comment: Still discontinuous at a point.  We would have to exclude the point of discontinuity from the derivative.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  You have to do that with either domain.  Heck, you have to do it with $\tan$ and $1/x$.  What's the big deal?

Comment: Derivatives of discontinuous functions have always made me lose it since high school :-S .

Comment: If this is the domain, then what would I do to get my answer? I'm not sure how I could define the answer within these parameters.

Comment: This domain uses the 1st and 3rd Quadrants for $\sec.$  Since your values are negative, you're in the 3rd Quadrant.  Find a 3rd Quadrant angle with the same $\sec$ and $5\pi/6$ and $3\pi/4.$